# Should I use an intermediate variable in a complex C# expression?

Tags: c#

Can anyone please tell which one is the more effective way to write C# code, among the two options below?

Option A:

```
internal static string GetLast3Years()
{
    return (DateTime.Now.Year - 2).ToString() + "," + (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString() + "," + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
}
```

Or option B:

```
internal static string GetLast3Years()
{
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    return (currentYear - 2).ToString() + "," + (currentYear - 1).ToString() + "," + currentYear.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Neither is particularly good...

Comment: Option B, because it fetches the value only once. Ugly code though.

Comment: Maybe the second option is better, as you get only once DateTime.Now and cache it in an int variable, anyway I don't thing there is much difference in this case.

Comment: You should not usually worry about such trivial optimizations. A lot of times a release build and the CLR itself will take care of such things. Alternatively you could test which one is better in `your context` yourself with some diagnoses.

Comment: @VasilTrifonov _Cached_ in an int variable?

Comment: With respect to the other comments, you may find that both are the same performance wise as the values may get inlined at compile time - the only way you can test which is the `best` is by testing. Also, what if you decide that you want the last 4 years. Last 5 years? Last 100 Years? Regardless of how neat the code is, your implementation is now fixed. What if you wanted the Last 3 years from a date in the past?

Comment: I'd use: `return string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year-2, 3));`

Comment: @Servy That's brilliant as you can also parameterize every part of it; the start, and even the offset. Effectively - `GetNYearsFromDate(int startYear, int offset, int numberOfYears)`

Comment: @dash Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Servy Nice, though that's a lot slower than the other two methods provided.

Comment: @DGibbs Did you actually time it at all?  I would doubt it's significantly different.  It's more likely to just be a tiny bit slower.  Also this is almost certainly not a performance bottleneck in code; making the code "better" for a method like this is all about making it more readable, easier to maintain or generalize, etc.  If it happens to take a few nanoseconds longer nobody is ever going to know.

Comment: @Servy Method A: 0.65ns, Method B: 0.15ns, Method C (yours): 3.43ns. Though it is obviously much more flexible/readable than the code OP has posted, plus _"premature optimization is the root of all evil"_ as a wise man once said.

Answer (score 2):

Note that semantically these options are not equal.

There is a chance (very-very small) that first option will output smth like `2011,2012,2014`, so second option is better at least because it will always generate consistent results (3 consecutive years).

But second option is also quite cluttered. There is a [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) method that is able to combine different values with separator, so your code may look like:

```
internal static string GetLast3Years()
{
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    return string.Join(",", currentYear - 2, currentYear - 1, currentYear);
}
```

But the question is still why would you need a string representation of last 3 years, comma-separated. I would consider having a method that will return enumerable of last N years instead...

Answer (score 1):

I will do it the following way

```
  internal static string GetLast3Years()
        {
            int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;       

            return String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", currentYear - 2, currentYear - 1, currentYear);
        }
```

Comment: technically not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy  He wants the more effective way of writing between the two options he wrote. and I modify it and give him a better solution. What is the problem

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than the code in the OP rather than just say you would do it a certain way, and not provide any reasoning?

Comment: @DanHunex No, that's not what he asked at all.  He asked which of the two options provided is better, he didn't ask for a third option that's better than both.

Comment: @Servy, you give him third option in the comment above . Btw, Yes I choose the second method he wrote but improved. U still didnt get

Comment: @DanHunex You are correct I did.  I was not answering the question when I provided that code, which is why it was posted as a comment and not an answer.  No, you didn't say to use option B, you just incorporated part of that option in your answer.  Your "answer" also has no explanation of it's code, no reasoning for your decisions, etc.